# Creating 3D tileset

Tags: modeling, mesh

My goal is to create a 3D terrain tileset for a game.
I can't however find a good way to make sure that the edges of the multiple tiles (outer corner, inner corner, edge, slopes) fit seamlessly to each other.

Are there known tools or tricks to create 3d seamless tilesets like these?

Example
[image: Example]

Example
[image: Example]

[image: Example]

Comment: Try using ultimate grid snap to keep them in a grid space in Blender, then joining the meshes together and seeing if everything connects correctly when you use merge by distance.

Comment: That's what I'd recommend, too. I don't make game assets myself but sometimes watch tutorials for making them, and usually people use grid snapping (with _Absolute Grid Snap_ enabled, I guess).